# get the value of first cell of last row

Tags: jquery

I would like to grab the value of first cell of the last row of the table but it seems the syntax is not correct. Could you please check.

```
var id = $(this).closest('table').children('tr last').children('td first').text();

var id = $(this).closest('table tr:last-child td:first-child').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "first cell of the last row", you can:

```
var id = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last td:first').text();
```

Of course, that'd only work if `this` is an element under the `table` you are trying to get the values from.

Notice also **`id` is a string**, even though the content of the cell is a number. If you want to perform numeric operations on it, you'd have to **use `parseInt(id)` to convert it into an integer**.

Runnable demo snippet below.

```js
var thizz = document.getElementById('someElementUnderTable');
var id = $(thizz).closest('table').find('tr:last td:first').text();

var new_id = parseInt(id) + 1;


alert('Original was: '+id+'\nAfter adding one: '+new_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="someElementUnderTable"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var id = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').last().find('td').first().text();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I would also like to know how I can add 1 to that value. For example I get **var id = 5**, then I want to create a new variable **var new_id = id + 1**. I should get 6 as a result but I get 51. Could you help me please.

Comment: after you get the value you could just do id++;  see here http://jsfiddle.net/kqL83dx3/2/

@EducateYourself

Comment: Actually it is retuning a string you need to convert it to number, var new_id = Number(id)+1 , will work
 pleasure

Answer (score 1):

How about getting it outisde `this`:

```
$('table#myTable > tr:last-child > td:first-child').text();
```

If `this` is a child of the table, then something like this:

```
$(this).parents('table').find('> tr:last-child > td:first-child').text();
```

Or if not,

```
$(this).closest('table').find('> tr:last-child > td:first-child').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also select it by the ID.  Check out this JS Fiddle for the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/kqL83dx3/1/

```
var id = $('#test tr:last td:first').text();
```